# Show that $s_{n+1} = \sqrt{2 + \sqrt{s_n}}$ is an increasing sequence, where $s_1 = \sqrt{2}$

Tags: sequences-and-series

We know that $s_n < 2$. I am assuming we need to use this fact?

Answer (score 3):

Proof by induction. We have $s_2 = \sqrt{2 + \sqrt{2}} > \sqrt{2} = s_1$ and if $s_n > s_{n-1}$ for some $n > 1$, then $$s_{n+1} = \sqrt{2 + \sqrt{s_n}} > \sqrt{2 + \sqrt{s_{n-1}}} = s_n.$$ Therefore by induction, $s_{n+1} > s_n$ for all $n \in \Bbb N$.